# Is dimension unique?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

To what extent can we describe a space as being uniquely n-dimensional?
For example, the space of functions on I=[0,1] are frequently described as infinite dimensional, where I serves as the index for the infinite dimensions, with each dimension related to a given x in the domain of the functions.
At the same time, an uncountably infinite number of functions on I=[0,1] can be described with a 2-D object in 3-D space. 
So which is it?  Do the functions on [0,1] create a two dimension space, or an infinite dimensional space?  Or are both descriptions correct, depending upon purpose and usage?

Answer (score 2):

The space of real-valued functions on $[0,1]$ is a [vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) that does not have a finite basis, so it is infinite-dimensional. You can continuously imbed real Euclidean space of any finite dimension into the space of real-valued functions on $[0,1]$, so since one cannot imbed a Euclidean space into another Euclidean space of smaller dimension, it is not possible to imbed the space of real-valued functions continuously into Euclidean space of any finite dimension. By the usual definition of topological dimension, therefore, the space of functions on $[0,1]$ is infinite-dimensional topologically as well.